# How to use the sheet name from cell in formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to reference another sheet in a formula based on a cell value.

I have a workbook with 3 sheets 'Formulas', 'Letters', and 'Numbers'. On the Formulas sheet cell B1 is a list of the sheet names ie: 'Letters' or 'Numbers'. Cell B2 is a list of values 1-4.

I want to use a formula in B4 to VLookup on the 'Letters' or 'Numbers' sheet based on what is selected in Cell B1, ie: the sheet name.

When I try to put the cell with sheet names in it in the Vlookup formula it opens a dialogue for me to pick a workbook.

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'B1'!A1:B4,2,0)
```

Comment: [`INDIRECT()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

Comment: https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/functions/indirect-function/

Comment: What confuses people is they “hard code” the sheet name into the formula and it works.  But then they enter a formula and it doesn’t.  Using any formula to derive a text string as a reference—including concatenation with “&”, has to be enclosed in an INDIRECT().

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution using `INDIRECT()` [here](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/719933-select-which-worksheet-based-on-cell-value.html):

For my example:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,INDIRECT("'"&B1&"'!A1:B4"),2,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that INDIRECT() is volatile, i.e. it can slow down workbooks because it causes re-calculation after ANYTHING changes in the workbook.

If your sheet name is in cell B1, you can use a non-volatile approach with modern functions like IFS() or SWITCH().

```
=IFS(B1="Formulas",VLOOKUP(B2,Formulas!A1:B4,2,0),B1="Letters",VLOOKUP(B2,Letters!A1:B4,2,0),B1="Numbers",VLOOKUP(B2,Numbers!A1:B4,2,0))

=SWITCH(B1,"Formulas",VLOOKUP(B2,Formulas!A1:B4,2,0),"Letters",VLOOKUP(B2,Letters!A1:B4,2,0),"Numbers",VLOOKUP(B2,Numbers!A1:B4,2,0))
```

The setup is a bit more work, but in the long run, the workbook will make up for that by calculating faster.